# Mysql/Mariadb - Speed up query with varchar columns already indexed but index its first 2 characters (USxxxxxxxx, CAxxxxxxxx, etc)

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, varchar

On my project (MariaDB 10.3), I use a table for storing data per ISIN code (a financial asset identifier). For instance, "US3696041033" for General Electric.

I have 4 Millions rows in my table.
Each code starts with 2 characters ("US", "CA", "FR", etc) and then a mix of letters and digits.
I already have an index on this column but I am looking for a solution to speed up queries.

Is there a way to index on the same column but to only index the 2 first characters in order to first limit the search to only rows with the same first 2 characters and then the index already in place helps to "finish" the search ?

Thanks in advance.
Arnaud

Comment: Why do you think that adding an index on the first two characters of an already indexed column will help? Looks like an X-Y Problem™ to me. Please consider reading [this advice](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: While it may be technically possible to do (as per Ergest's answer) it won't help performance in your use case. Your index already stores the data sorted by the values of the `ISIN`s which would then be already sorted by the first 2 characters of those `ISIN`s. A separate index on *only the first 2 characters* would be a subset of the use cases your current index already covers. You don't have a ton of data, so if you have a query that's particularly slow, then it's probably an issue with the query or how you architected your system, and looking at the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` would be the way to go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We currently query the table with an "WHERE isin IN (%implode liste of isins%)" as this table is shared between several environments. We can search for several thousands ISINs in the same query. So if I understand correctly, the only way to improve the query performance would be a query with "WHERE EXISTS" instead of "WHERE IN" (but we would need a temporary table to store the list of ISIN for the subquery), or to use the table as a IN MEMORY TABLE (the content do not change often).

Comment: If you want performance help for a specific query, it's best you post a new question with details such as your table structure, 
the indexes on those tables, the query itself, and the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE`. But the performance problem you're running into is a pretty common one when using the `IN` operator and generally rather easy to fix. Using a temporary table is usually a good solution and I prefer joining to that temporary table directly, as it's the most relational solution IMO. Another solution is to rewrite the query to use `UNION` against each value in the `IN` operator, when practical.

Comment: Regardless, you don't have an indexing issue, rather a query tuning one.

Comment: You could create a identical tables for each prefix.  That would reduce the number of rows per table.  I am not sure what performance gains you would get if any.

Answer (score 0):

```
WHERE col LIKE 'US%'
```

will [probably] use the index that you already have, and use it efficiently.

I say "probably" because if more than (about) 20% of the table matches, the index will be [correctly] ignored.  That is, simply scanning the table will be faster than bouncing between the index and the data.

That is, you may find the index being used for most prefixes, but not for, say, 'US'.  Don't fret; that is valid and cannot be improved upon.  Use `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` on the 4M-row table to see this.

There is no need to consider `INDEX(col(2))` -- such "prefixing" exists, but I don't recommend it.

The above applies to a single prefix being asked about.

**Several thousands ISINs in the same query**

That needs to be part of the Question.  It changes the answer significantly.

For multiple prefixes, I recommend this:

```
WHERE col REGEXP '^(AB|XY|RR|FX|MO)'
```

That will ignore the index and scan the table.  But again, that is the best possible.

Further, the prefixes don't have to be the same length.

(`LIKE` has no corresponding syntax.)

Please provide a sample of the *full* query.  Other clauses in `WHERE`, the addition of `ORDER BY`, etc, etc, *may* influence optimization.

Comment: It is a very simple query : SELECT * FROM `esg_2022_09_02` WHERE id in ( "XS1319820541", "XS1394791492", ...). There is no ORDER BY. On a big sample, we get 800k lines in the result (35MB). The data query + transfer takes 10 seconds. I tried $bdd->setAttribute(\PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY, false); to disable buffer & Cie but is only helped memory usage but not the processing time. From your messages, I understand it is not a query problem but only a data transfer time (although the database server is on the same VMware private cloud)

Comment: @moe69230 - Yes, I would expect the shoveling of 35MB to be the main consumer of time.  What will the client do with the data?  I would expect the "buffered" to have some impact due to the "first" rows to arrive sooner in one case than the other.

Comment: @moe69230 - Also, is that IN list _all_ the XS items?  Some of the cost of the query is parsing such a huge query.  `LIKE "XS%"` would run faster.